# Visual studio lightswitch upload and download files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, lightswitch-2013

I am following this article to upload and download files using silverlight child window.
http://gyansangrah.com/ArticleContent.aspx?ID=upload_and_download_file_in_lightswitch_2011

I am using 2013 though. I have referenced my download.aspx page in the lsxtproj file <_BuildFile Include="Server\Upload\Download.aspx">.

I can upload files no problems however when I download them I get a http 404 error.
It is trying to look for this URL.
http://localhost:54853/Client/Download.aspx?id=6
Requested URL: /Client/Download.aspx

I have my Download.aspx file in the server project and referenced it in my lsxtproj file.

I dont know why it will throw back http 404 error when trying to download the file using the command button.

Thanks

Comment: The example uses ServerGenerated\Download.aspx in the project file, which implies (all other things being equal) that it will be found in the application root. You've used Server\Upload\Download.aspx which implies you're using a subdirectory. Have you tried  http://localhost:54853/Client/Upload/Download.aspx?id=6 for the URL?

Comment: ServerGenerated folder isnt available in 2013 only the server folder. I have gotten rid of the Upload subdirectory. So I am trying to achieve the same URL in the article. However mine comes up looking for the client folder but the article doesnt. I have a download.aspx in my server folder.

Comment: In his article it doesnt show the client subdirectory in the URL

Comment: I just tried something if I remove client from the URL http://localhost:54853/Download.aspx?id=1002

Comment: it works once I remove Client from the URL

Answer (score 0):

I Solve this problem by changing the Download_Execute() function by this;

```
partial void Download_Execute()
    {
        int fileId = this.FileCollection.SelectedItem.Id;
        Uri hostUri = null;
        Dispatchers.Main.Invoke(() =>
        {
            hostUri = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Source;

        });


        Dispatchers.Main.Invoke(() =>
        {
            UriBuilder myUri = new UriBuilder(hostUri.Scheme, hostUri.Host, hostUri.Port, "Download.aspx",
               "?Id=" + fileId);

            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myUri.Uri, "_new");
        });


    }
```

and changed the phrase in the lsxtproj  file as this;

```
<_BuildFile Include="Download.aspx">
      <SubFolder>
      </SubFolder>
      <PublishType>
      </PublishType>
    </_BuildFile>
```